# How to extract p-values from sumurca object?

Tags: r

I'd like to extract the p-values from the summary output of `ur.za` in package `urca`.

```
library(urca)
data(nporg)
gnp <- na.omit(nporg[, "gnp.r"])
za.gnp <- ur.za(gnp, model="both", lag=2)
summary(za.gnp)

> summary(za.gnp)

################################ 
# Zivot-Andrews Unit Root Test # 
################################ 


Call:
lm(formula = testmat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-39.753  -9.413   2.138   9.934  22.977 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  21.49068   10.25301   2.096  0.04096 *  
y.l1          0.77341    0.05896  13.118  < 2e-16 ***
trend         1.19804    0.66346   1.806  0.07675 .  
y.dl1         0.39699    0.12608   3.149  0.00272 ** 
y.dl2         0.10503    0.13401   0.784  0.43676    
du          -25.44710    9.20734  -2.764  0.00788 ** 
dt            2.11456    0.84179   2.512  0.01515 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13.72 on 52 degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9948,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9942 
F-statistic:  1651 on 6 and 52 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Teststatistic: -3.8431 
Critical values: 0.01= -5.57 0.05= -5.08 0.1= -4.82 

Potential break point at position: 21
```

All methods I found for `lm` summary objects don't seem to work here. And I've spent quite some time searching through `str(summary(za.gnp))` to no avail. Any hints on where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects of class `ur.za` are S4 objects, which behave differently to S3 objects like those produced by `lm`. One difference is the concept of the slot accessed via the `@` operator.

`summary(za.gnp)` has `pval` slot but its value is `NULL`.

```
summary(za.gnp)@pval
NULL
```

However, it also has a `testreg` slot which contains an `lm` object with the test results that you can use to obtain the p values in the usual way:

```
coef(summary(summary(za.gnp)@testreg))[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
 (Intercept)         y.l1        trend        y.dl1        y.dl2           du 
4.096351e-02 4.007914e-18 7.674887e-02 2.716223e-03 4.367588e-01 7.884201e-03 
          dt 
1.514797e-02
```